# Transferring Gnucash transactions to another Gnucash account

Tags: gnucash

What is the best way to export/import transaction from a Gnucash file to another Gnucash file?

The most obvious (and actually only way I can find) is to Export Transactions to CSV... and then to import from your other account.
But CSV import doesn't allow to import all of Gnucash information categories, and at best can only recreate basic transaction.

For instance in the exported CSV, all the splits are included, and actually all the details of each every transactions.
But when you try to import such a file, you get errors for all the lines that don't include Dates (all the splits) to start with, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you close the account it gives you the option to transfer the transactions to a different account.

Comment: This is a very easy way to move all transactions from one account to another.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

1. Change the view from "Basic Ledger" to "Transaction Journal" (from "View" drop-down menu).
2. Click on the account box, open the drop-down menu, and select the new account

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this is to edit the Gnucash XML file itself, and add the transactions from the other book manually.

You have to change the guid of all the accounts to match the ones of the destination book.

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the (new) account number into the 'account' field - and you are done. Yes it is that easy - provided you know the account number ...
I am (in Germany) using for over ten years a worked-out SKR04 that shows the acount numbers prepended to the account's text which makes working with GnuCash a pleasure. The SKR04 from the GnuCash is practically *unusable*, since it does not show provide account numbers in the account's text - which makes the whole thing a blind-flight.
See here for worked-out SKR04 (German)...
https://www.facebook.com/GnuCash-DE-400197317114290/